# QLineSeries does not show up when working with numbers < 1e-14

Tags: c++, qt, qtcharts

When graphing a line series within a small range using QtChart library (for example, between 0 and 1e-15), the line series seemingly does not get rendered. Using larger numbers with the same exact code works perfectly.

I've tried boiling down my code to be as simple as possible, to find any mistakes I was making, but I cannot find any. I suspect this may be a bug in Qt, but I'm posting here in case I missed something before I file a bug report.

I've also failed to find any information online about people experiencing similar bugs, but that may just be an indication that my google-fu is weak.

I originally encountered this bug using PyQt5, but have recreated it in C++ to ensure it was not a PyQt5 specific bug.

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtCharts/QChartView>
#include <QtCharts/QLineSeries>
#include <QtCharts/QLegend>
#include <QtCharts/QValueAxis>

QT_CHARTS_USE_NAMESPACE

#define FACTOR 1e-13

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QLineSeries *lineseries = new QLineSeries();
    lineseries->setName("series");
    lineseries->setUseOpenGL(true);

    for (double i = 0.0; i < 10.0; i += 1.0)
        lineseries->append(QPointF(i*FACTOR, i * FACTOR));

    QChart *chart = new QChart();
    chart->addSeries(lineseries);
    chart->setTitle("Line example");

    QValueAxis *axisX = new QValueAxis();
    chart->setAxisX(axisX, lineseries);

    QValueAxis *axisY = new QValueAxis();
    chart->setAxisY(axisY, lineseries);
    axisY->setRange(0.0, 9.0*FACTOR);

    axisX->setLabelFormat("%.3E");
    axisY->setLabelFormat("%.3E");

    chart->legend()->setVisible(true);
    chart->legend()->setAlignment(Qt::AlignBottom);

    QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);
    chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    QMainWindow window;
    window.setCentralWidget(chartView);
    window.resize(840, 900);
    window.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Running the code attached, I would expect to observe a linear line series rendered in the plot, but I see nothing rendered.

Modifying the `FACTOR` constant to something >= 1e-12 will make the line series display properly.

Comment: I think it is a limitation that is not documented so for me at least there is a bug in the same functionality (because something expected does not work) or in the docs (since that behavior is not signaled). Report it

Comment: @eyllanesc I've filed the report here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-76416 if you have anything you'd like to ad about your experience with this bug please post it there :)